# Error in PCL projects (MT0011 was built against a more recent runtime (NET_4_0) than MonoTouch supports.)

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

When i try to deploy my solution from Visual Studio 2012 to a ipad Device or simulator, all PCL projects are giving error like:

MT0011:Cirrious.CrossCore.dll 
was built against a more recent runtime (NET_4_0) than MonoTouch supports.

I tried to do Clean and Rebuild all solution with success.
My Xamarin.iOS version is 1.1.200 (stable).

My MonoTouch.xml file in 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile104\SupportedFrameworks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Framework DisplayName="MonoTouch" 
    Identifier="MonoTouch"  
    Profile="*"  
    MinimumVersion="*"  
    MaximumVersion="4.0" />
```

My VS information:

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Ultimate

GhostDoc   4.5.13017.0
GhostDoc automatically generates XML documentation comments.

Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone   6.2.923.0
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone
Build 6.2.923.0

Microsoft XNA Game Studio   4.0
Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0
Build 4.0.40906.0

NuGet Package Manager   2.2.40116.9051
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Web Developer Tools   1.2.40308.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Page Inspector: Tool that offers an efficient way to decompose Web Applications and diagnose front-end issues.
Web Publishing: Extensions required for Web Publishing for both hosted servers as well as on premises.
Web Form Templates: Includes the default templates for Web Form Applications.
Editor Extensions: Includes HTML, CSS, and JS editor extensions that greatly enhance the development experience.

Xamarin.Android   4.6.08007 (0cc7ae3b)
Visual Studio plugin to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   1.1.200 (7d63692c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS

The solution contain projects and not the build Dll.
The problem must be in my pc because a colleague of mine can deploy the same solution to the same pc mac.

Thank you in advance for help,
Paulo Dias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `MT0011` is a **warning** not an error. It's mean to tell you that some stuff might not work or build correctly later.

> My Xamarin.iOS version is 1.1.200

That looks like the version of the add-in for Visual Studio. This is not the version of Xamarin.iOS itself.

To support .NET 4.0 assemblies you need to use Xamarin.iOS 6.3+ which is, right now. available on our **beta** channel. On promoted to stable it will be known as **6.4**.

The current **stable** release of Xamarin.iOS is 6.2.7. This version is based on Mono 2.10 and still use the 2.1, Silverlight-like, BCL assemblies (which explains your warning).

Comment: My mac pc info: Xamarin Studio: 4.0.9, Apple Developer tools Xcode 4.6, Xamarin.Ios vesion 6.2.7.1

Comment: Now new error: Error 44 MT2002:Failed to resolve "System.Decimal ::StringToDecimal(System.String)" reference from XXXX.Touch.csproj]

Comment: Did not you said (earlier/deleted) that you still had the same error ? Errors like `MT2002` can occurs when you mix assemblies binaries built separately (but still reference each others). Make sure you rebuild every assemblies using the same Xamarin.iOS release.

Comment: Also maybe go slowly. If you have one setup that works and one serup that doesn't, then take 10 minutes looking for differences for every 10 seconds spent making changes. It may only take one small change to fix it.

Comment: sorry for all confusion. Errors MT0011 and MT2002 disappeared after update to channel Beta (mac and windows pc). Now i can build to Simulator but not to Device (iPAD with iOS 6.1.3), with error remote build host failed... I tried to do deploy a sample project (Babel) and it worked in device...

Comment: I analyzed buid log and found that there was another error (MT3001 could not AOT the assembly), "before remote build host failed". After search some blogs I added "-v -v -v" to additional mtouch arguments and appeared another error (MT4112 fount a generic type...). Code where this error appear works well before the updates.